# Aplicativo não aparece na lista de app com que se pode compartilhar um conteúdo

Tags: java, android

Bom eu tenho um aplicativo que serve para baixar e assistir vídeos online, uma coisa que já estou tentando fazer a algum tempo é fazer com que meu aplicativo apareça na lista ao compartilhar um link ou uma página html.

Eis meu manifesto:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samuelives.videoplayer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.samuelives.videoplayer.Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.samuelives.videoplayer.player.Player"/>

        <!-- Activity responsável por abrir links externos ou páginas, supostamente deveria fazer com que aparecesse na lista de aplicativos ao compartilhar um conteúdo--> 
        <activity android:name="com.samuelives.videoplayer.MainNoGui">

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.samuelives.videoplayer.Main"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/php"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/x-php"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/php"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-php"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-httpd-php"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-httpd-php-source"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <!--Cast Activity-->

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Mas eis o que resulta:

[image: página 1] [image: página 2] [image: página 3]

Simplesmente não aparece na lista

Comment: O botão compartilhar do chrome não compartilha o _texto_ da URL? Sendo assim não entra nos teus intent-filters?

Comment: O meu app esta aparecendo quando eu clico em um link no app do youtube por exemplo, mas não na ação de compartilhar